# 3d diagonal flip is not working

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a page with a bunch of boxes on it. There are four types of box. I want 4 different css3 transitions.

Box 1 - flip on Y axis on hover <- this works flawlessly
Box 2 - flip on X axis on hover <- this works flawlessly
Box 3 - fade effect on hover <- this works flawlessly
Box 4 - flip on X & Y axis diagonally on hover <- this sorta works at first and then doesn't

Each box has the same mark-up:

```
<div class="box box-4">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="front"><img src="some_pic.jpg"></div>
        <div class="back">
            <div class="tools"><!-- some links and stuff --></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when box-4 starts out, it looks perfect, the front is the right way up, the back is hidden, as it should be. When you hover on it, the animation starts out right, it flips on a diagonal axis (top-left corner to bottom-right corner), but then when the animation ends, the front (which should be visible behind the back but reversed) is perpendicular to the back!

[image]

I've tweaked the CSS values in all imaginable ways, I've looked at a ton of demos, what is wrong?!

CSS:

```
.box-4 { -webkit-perspective:1200px; }
.box-4 .inner-container { 
       width:100%; height:100%; position:relative; 
       -webkit-ransition:all 0.4s ease-in-out; 
       -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d; 
}
.box-4 .back { 
    width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; 
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.6); 
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; 
    -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d; 
 }
.box-4:hover .inner-container { -webkit-transform:rotate3d(45,45,0,180deg); }
.box-4 .back { -webkit-transform:rotate3d(45,45,0,-180deg); }
```

Note: I'm showing just the -webkit- styles here for simplicity, but in my actual CSS I have -moz-, -o-, -ms- and the regular un-prefixed variants as well...

Comment: Could do, might take a little while...

Comment: ok, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6KLYs/1/ it's not 100% faithful because I can't get the front to even flip for some reason. So ignore the fact that the blue box doesn't flip, it does in my actual page. But you can see when the pink box flips into view, it has the blue bits sticking out the top and bottom..

Comment: The blue actually does flip when using Firefox (replacing `webkit` with `moz` in the CSS), but yes, I do see your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, uh... I got it to work by switching the CSS for the front and back while maintaining the colors for those two, as well as removing the transform for what was once the back and is now the front. (The transform was the first thing I figured out, because in your original the transformation on the back was simply being undone by the hover transformation, orienting it as it would normally be (horizontally-aligned), but once I removed that the colors were switched around for some reason.)

http://jsfiddle.net/6KLYs/4/

Not sure if it'll work in browsers that use `-webkit-` (Safari and Chrome, I believe?) instead of `-moz-`, though.

---

With the clarification about how you want the final orientation, here's one that I believe should now work the way you want it. I just changed things back a bit, added the transparency, and included a scaling operation in the hover transform to go with the rotate.

http://jsfiddle.net/6KLYs/6/

An additional 90-degree rotation on the z-axis would also work ( http://jsfiddle.net/6KLYs/7/), but I think the scaling looks better.

Comment: thanks, weirdly in firefox I get the same issue but reversed - so there are pink bits sticking out the top and bottom :/ I need to get it working in chrome too though. I guess if I can't get it working I'll have to go with one of the other anims, but it should work, I've seen similar demos work in chrome...

Comment: Considering that most browsers will simply ignore CSS attributes they don't recognize (though Firefox, at least, does print warnings about them to the error console), I think you could include multiple sets differentiated for the various browsers using those `-moz`, `-webkit`, etc. prefixes. What happens when you try to use it in Chrome (with `-moz` switched back to `-webkit`, of course)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using all the various prefixes (when I say all, I mean the regular ones), I just left them out so the CSS is readable and not just a great monolithic block of code! Same issue with your fiddle as with firefox, pink bits top and bottom

Comment: "Pink bits top and bottom." I'm guessing there's some issue with `rotate3D` in certain browsers and browser versions, as if the divs have the same orientation to start with, they should be rotating together as it's the container that's rotating, not the front/back divs themselves. For clarification, though: is the behavior you want for the previously blue, wider-than-tall rectangle to become taller-than-wide and pink when hovered over?

Comment: Not quite, both front and back should be rectangular, wider than they are tall. I've used this page for reference (along with many others!): http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php the only difference is theirs are square whereas I need rectangles. So when the page loads you should be able to see the front but *not* the back at all. On hover it should transition so you can see the back and because the back is opaque, you can see the front *behind* it, but not poking out above and below

Comment: Flipping a rectangle diagonally will switch the dimensions. You need to not only flip but also perform a scaling transformation in order to make the rectangle appear to have the same dimensions as before. Also, I believe you mean "transparent", not "opaque". Anyway, I updated my answer with a version that should work the way I now understand your requirements.

Comment: ha, yes I meant transparent. Or semi-opaque. Or semi-transparent! It's a little better now in that the front is the same size when it's flipped. However, it's horribly stretched and the back is also stretched - it's twice as wide as it should be and half as high. I tried to counter it by reversing the scale and adding it to the transform for the .back and that did no good at all :\ man this is frustrating the hell out of me...But, I didn't know it got scaled as well, so I'm going to pursue this further. Thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: Yeah, number 6 is working exactly as it should in firefox now. In chrome the back flips as it should, the but the front just stays put. Gonna keep trying with Chrome...thanks